# Default styles with internal custom controls (C# Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, xamlparseexception

I am trying to create a Silverlight custom control that derives from `System.Windows.Controls.Control` with visibility `internal`, but I am seeing problems when trying to apply a default style. Here's the simplest form of the class ...

```
internal class MyClass : Control
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyClass);
    }
}
```

... and here's a simple form of the default style in `generic.xaml` ...

```
<Style TargetType="controls:MyClass">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
</Style>
```

Although this control doesn't do anything useful, it is possible to create an instance of it, but only if its visibility is `public`. When the class is marked `internal`, the application raises the following runtime error:

```
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ParserError       
Message: No matching constructor found on type 'MyClass'.     
File:      
Line: 11     
Position: 40
```

Can you please advise what I need to do to make an internal control class visible to the Xaml parser.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: +1 because I had this same error message and for my purpose, making the class public is good enough, so this solved my problem.

Comment: +1 because I encountered this problem with an internal class that is used in my Application.Resources dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Most late-binding scenarios use reflection and require the methods/members/properties to be public.

Why can you not leave it public in this instance?

Comment: It's not a single class - it a whole namespace of classes that are not intended to be consumed by the end user of my library. The CLR has numerous internal classes, so I don't think I am trying to do something unreasonable, am I?